# wp rest api get posts with their meta

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

I am a total wp newb and I am struggling to get posts with all their meta(wp_postmeta table) via the WP REST API.
http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found an easy solution for this. In the current theme - functions.php add the following code:

```
register_rest_field( 'post', 'metadata', array(
    'get_callback' => function ( $data ) {
        return get_post_meta( $data['id'], '', '' );
    }, ));
```

It will return posts / post with all it's meta. I.e.
http://localhost/rest_api/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
or
http://localhost/rest_api/wp-json/wp/v2/post/58

post meta will be in "metadata"

Comment: Sos un genio viejo!!

Comment: This was so helpful, Thanks @Sorin Ciocoiu

Comment: For media, use `attachment` as object_type

Answer (score 6):

if you want single field use:

```
register_rest_field( 'post', 'views', array(
'get_callback' => function ( $data ) {
    return get_post_meta( $data['id'], 'hs_views', true );
}, ));
```

don't forget change hs_views field to what you want

if you want all fields use:

```
register_rest_field( 'post', 'meta', array(
'get_callback' => function ( $data ) {
    return get_post_meta( $data['id'], '', '' );
}, ));
```

check reference: [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: Thanks for this it got the views out for me in the WP API, can you also tell how to add this to a custom endpoint in a rest api request.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst register_rest_route is good for extensive customization, Wordpress allows you to expose custom meta fields in the default Wordpress REST API, without having to build your own endpoints.

You can use register_meta to expose certain Wordpress Meta fields for certain post types. By default, meta fields aren't registered to be exposed to the Rest API.

```
register_meta('post', 'type', [
        'type' => 'string',
        'single' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    ]);
```

In this example, we set default 'posts' to show the meta field with the key "type" in the rest api. Specifically, show_in_rest set to true achieves this.

Read More -> https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#using-register_rest_field-vs-register_meta