# How to add a post's view count into the WordPress API response

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

This is my first time working with Wordpress APIs, and i'm not a PHP developer. Essentially our client just wanted us to display WordPress articles in our react-native app with simple data like the:

- date
- title
- content
- thumbnail
- etc..

...anything you'd find in the default response, and this was easy. We simply used the default endpoints like this one: https://demo.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1015

Anyways... Our client now wants to display the "view count" of each article. However, i can't find that data in the default response:

[image]

Is there a way to get this view count data, and have it return in the API response, without having to customize every single endpoint?

Thanks

Comment: A post view count is not default functionality offered by WP, as far as I know - so I guess this must be using some kind of plugin, or is part of the specific theme’s functionality? You’d need to figure out where that stores this data first of all then. If it stores this as post meta data, there’s explanations available how to get that with the Rest API, like f.e. https://torquemag.io/2015/07/working-with-post-meta-data-using-the-wordpress-rest-api/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641689/wp-rest-api-get-posts-with-their-meta

Comment: Could you please check it - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286307/rest-api-hook-when-post-is-requested